# how calculate integral $\int \dot{x} \; dx$

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $x$ depend on $t$. $\dot{x}$ is derivative $x$ over $t$. I want to calculate the integral $\int \dot{x} \; dx$. I asked similar question about differentiation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103853/23998). Any thoughts and ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The case $\int \dot x dt$ is easier.

Comment: well, $\int \dot{x} dx =  \int \dot{x}^2 dt$

Comment: According to W.A. this integral has no solution in terms of elementary functions...

Comment: @pedja: That was I meant.

Comment: what is W.A.? You can post as an answer

Comment: @capoluca,WolframAlpha...online computational engine..

Comment: @capoluca : I find your comment incomprehensible.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MichaelHardy capuloca's comment is saying that a sum of infinitesimal ratios $\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot dx$ is the same as a sum of infinitesimal ratios $\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot dt$. And it is helpful for calculation if you have $x$ explictly in terms of $t$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The integral $\int \dot x dx$ cannot be evaluated explicitely unless the form of the function $x(t)$ is also given. This can be easily understood in the following way

$$\int \dot x dx=\int (\dot x)^2 dt$$

that cannot be furtherly explicited. This kind of computations generally come out from studies on mechanics with dissipative systems. If you have a differential equation like

$$\ddot x=-\dot x+F(x)$$

you can multiply both sides by $\dot x$ and integrating obtain

$$\int dt \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{{\dot x}^2}{2}\right)-\int dx F(x)=-\int \dot x dx$$

that cannot be reduced anymore even if lhs can be expressed through an energy integral.

Comment: can you explain more about the last equation, plz. Why from that you conclude that there is no solution? Thanks

Comment: @capoluca: I am not implying that there is no solution but that, in order to evaluate your integral, you will need to know $x(t)$ explicitly, solving the original ode. In this way you are able to evaluate the integral on the rhs that is your problem.

Answer (score -5):

You can write it as $\int \frac{dx}{dt}dx$ which, assuming appropriate smoothness conditions on $\dot{x}$ is the same as $\frac{d}{dt}\int x dx = \frac{d}{dt} (\frac{x^2}{2} + C) = x\dot{x}$

Comment: could explain details plz, why can we put derivation over t outside of the integral? and by the way you don't have constant in the answer, however, you should have one.

Comment: Moreover, if you take derivative of your answer you would not get $\dot{x}$

Comment: Can someone down vote this answer, it is wrong